# Power M function to return most common string of a column as part of a Table.Group aggregate clause

Tags: powerbi, m

I have written a custom aggregate function to return the most common value for one or more columns for a set of records which have a unique grouping: ie that you can use where you might use MAX, MIN etc but the result is the most commonly occurring value. 
Can anyone advise on a better or more performant solution? It is my first M function. Or feel free to adapt.

Functionality if grouping on col G1 and aggregating on col A1 with the first table as input data you would get the 2nd table as output.

[image]

[image]

Function MostCommon

```
let 
    fnMostCommon = (ListIn)  =>
    let
    uniquevalues=List.Distinct(ListIn),
    result=Table.FromList(uniquevalues,null,{"u"}),
    result2=Table.AddColumn(result ,"freq", each List.Count(List.PositionOf(ListIn, [u], 100))),
    result3 = Table.Sort(result2,{{"freq", Order.Descending},{"u",Order.Ascending}}),
    result4 = List.First(result3[u])
    in result4
    in fnMostCommon
```

Code to create data and run:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUQozhBCxOlC+ETa+EZifhKY+CU19MpAJRGUm6LxYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [G1 = _t, A1 = _t, A2 = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"G1", type text}, {"A1", type text}, {"A2", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"G1"}, {{"Agg", each MostCommon([A1]), type text}, {"Agg2", each AllConcat([A1]), type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Agg2"})
```

in
    #"Removed Columns"

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUQozVIrVgTKN0JlJCAVJCNFkIBOJEQsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [G1 = _t, A1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"G1", type text}, {"A1", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"G1"}, {{"Count", each Table.First(Table.Sort(Table.Group(_, "A1", {"Count", List.Count}), {"Count"}))[A1], type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Everything is handled in the last step which I've expanded out below:

```
Table.Group(
    #"Changed Type",
    {"G1"},
    {{
      "Count",
      each Table.First(
               Table.Sort(
                   Table.Group(_, "A1", {"Count", List.Count}),
                   {"Count"}
               )
           )[A1],
      type text
    }}
)
```

This groups by the `G1` column and for each `G1` value, it calculates a grouped table with each `A1` value and the count that value occurs. I.e., the grouped table for the `a` row is

```
A1  Count
---------
V1  1
V2  2
```

It then sorts by count (`Table.Sort`), selects the top row (`Table.First`), and returns the value in the `[A1]` column, which is `V2` in the `a` row example.

Comment: Thank you. I reckon the Sort by Count needs to Descending. And to be consistent with my function also sorted by A1. Do you know if it is more efficient than the function? I prefer the function for readability - MostCommon just becomes another aggregate function like MAX. But it does need to be quick

Comment: Sort should default to descending. You can certainly factor out the aggregation into a separate function as you did, if you prefer (definitely a good idea if you want to use if more than once). I'd guess it's a bit faster but you really need to test it in practice to know for sure.